# Why is the visual angle equals 0.0213°

Tags: pixel, dpi

It's been said that the `Visual angle = object size / object distance`.

**Calculation**
One pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm's length. For a nominal arm's length of 28 inches, the visual angle is therefore about 0.0213 degrees.

`(1/96/28) = 0.00037 ≠ 0.0213`

**Update**

**Text Explanation**
*It is recommended that the reference pixel be the visual angle of one pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm's length. For a nominal arm's length of 28 inches, the visual angle is therefore about 0.0213 degrees.*

**Confusion 1**
Shouldn't it be **0.0213 radians**?

**Graphical Explanation**
[image]

**Confusion 2**
Shouldn't it be like that, even though the described sector should look much narrower?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle is expressed in radians, not in degrees. You need to convert between the two.

Comment: You seem to be a reasonable person, can you please clarify a bit of confusion created by the information I was learning before understanding what radians are. I've updated my question with basic information that people use to explain pixel ratio and it confuses when I compare it with what I've understood from academic data

Comment: 0.0213 degrees is correct. Converted to radians, it is 0.000372.

Which is exactly the result that 1/96/28 returns. This is a simple tangent operation taking two sides of a triangle (1/96 inches and 28 inches) and calculates an angle expressed in radians.